# R CMD INSTALL - save zip output in custom folder?

Tags: r, build, package, rstudio

Hello I am building a windows binary file of a R package using R CMD INSTALL (using RStudio button). is there a way to have the zip file automatically saved into a specific folder, instead of the default location?

Thank you

Comment: You could use `file.copy()` and `file.remove()`?

Comment: indeed, but that's a press on a button + 2 commands instead of simply clicking on a button.

Comment: You could perhaps write a Rstudio macro that would run building of a binary and then move the result to wherever you want.